# Converting word to pdf: Some hyperlinks don't work

Tags: ms-word

I am converting a word file into a pdf. Word version is 2016. I need to have hyperlinks active (References to sections, figures, etc.)
I use Export - Create a PDF/XPS Document and Optimized for Standard. 
I have references to figures and tables completely working, but references to sections don't work. In the Table of Content, I cannot click on the page numbers. What can be done to have links to sections working?

Answer (score 36):

To retain hyperlinks while converting word to pdf:

In word: Go to file, save as, choose option 'Best for electronic distribution and accessibility' and export.

Comment: This broke my line spacing, made my pdf document 1 page longer than my original docx.

Comment: Yeah this works, but it changes the document significantly (changes the font etc)

Answer (score 14):

Printing Word Document as PDF will deactivate all URL or link if it is inside a Text or Picture.

But if you use Save As PDF or Export as PDF  Option to make your PDF all URL or link will be active and you can click on that text or picture to visit your desired link or URL.

#### Using Save as Option

[image]

#### Using Export

[image]

Answer (score 4):

When you use *Export as PDF*,
make sure you are not on the option that says *Best for printing*
because your document is to be used for *Electronic* purposes.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Super simple way - Use the web version.

1. Visit [office.com](https://office.com).
2. Open **Word**.
3. Create/Upload the document.
4. Click on File tab -> Save As -> Download As PDF.

P.S. - On uploading the document if you found it distorted/broken in the web version, just go ahead and download the PDF, it will not be distorted.

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me:

1. Click on File -> Save As
2. In the popup, select the file type as PDF.
3. Click on the "Options" button.
4. Check the check box which says "PDF/A Compliant".
5. Click on OK and save the file in the required folder.

Also from what I've read, PDF/A is a better format for the future. Read more about it here: [PDF/A Compliance](https://www.gonitro.com/blog/how-to-use-pdfa)

Answer (score 1):

I used Save as Adobe PDF instead of Save As .. then select pdf format, none of the latter works. Save as Adobe PDF retained the hyperlinks for me, and the file size is a lot smaller too. [image]

Comment: Microsoft Word 2019 Office and Student for desktop has this under File->Export->Create PDF/XPS. thanks for this answer, I dont think i wouldve found or noticed this option otherwise. I dont see the difference between using this and using "Save As". But this method worked for me, "Save As" did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

And another answer, but since nobody wrote it yet:
In my PDF no links worked until I deleted all *internal links* to other places in the doc, like footnotes. Once I deleted all internal links the http-links worked again. Be aware: one single link breaks the whole document!

Comment: I removed all the links in the doc and readded them again, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on Options in Save As, the options dialog will pop up. Under "Include non-printing information check Create bookmarks using ... checkbox, and select Heading radio button.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did what you suggested and it didn't work. The links to figures and tables still work, but not to sections. I cannot figure out what is the problem...

Comment: I might used not headings but numbered items to refer to sections. It works very well in Word.

Comment: Strange, I just tested with 95 pages document containing TOC. Converting  to PDF preserved Bookmarks navigation. I think you right, that option specifically works with Headings.

Comment: I have fixed the TOC. I Made the TOC Look like Hyperlinks. Apparently, this was not done for the main TOC of sections. The TOC works now.

Comment: However, links to the sections from text don't work. I don't understand why this can happen.

Answer (score -3):

1. Under File, click "options".
2. Click on "Advanced" on the left side of the Word options pop up.
3. Uncheck "CTRL + Click to follow hyperlink"
4. Click "Ok".

Once you're done with this, proceed with converting your word file to pdf. The hyperlinks should be active now.